# uniform limit of integral of heat kernel

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

For any $(x,t)\in \Bbb R^n\times(0,+\infty)$. Let $$K(x,t)=\frac 1{{(4\pi t)}^{\frac n2}}e^{-\frac {|x|^2}{4t}}$$ be the heat kernel and consider $$u(x,t)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}K(x-y,t)u_0(y)dy$$.

Suppose $u_0$ is continuous in $\Bbb R^n$ and that $u_0(x)\to0$ uniformly as $x\to+\infty$

Prove that $t\to+ \infty$ $ u(x,t)=0$, uniformly in x.

I am preparing for qualifying exam so could you please answer this.

Comment: Do you know the maximum principle for the Cauchy problem? (Theorem 6 in §2.3 in Evans Book). From this proof you should see how to solve your problem. In particular, you need a case differentiation of "space-balls" related to the ratio $|x|^2/4t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. As $u_0$ goes to zero uniformly as $x \to \infty$, there is $r= r(\epsilon)$ such that

$$|u_0(x)| \leq \epsilon/2$$

for all $|x|\geq r$. Then

$$u(x, t) =\int_{B_{r}} K(x-y, t) u_0(y) dy + \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_{r}}K(x-y, t) u_0(y) dy$$

For the first term, as

$$|K(x-y, t)| = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}} e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}} \leq  \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{\frac{n}{2}}} $$

Let $T$ be large so that

$$ \int_{B_r} u_0(y)dy \leq (4\pi T)^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Thus $T$ depends only on $\epsilon$. The for all $t\geq T$,

$$\bigg|\int_{B_{r}} K(x-y, t) u_0(y) dy \bigg| \leq  \epsilon/2\ .$$

For the second term,

$$\bigg|\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_{r}}K(x-y, t) u_0(y) dy \bigg| \leq \epsilon /2 \bigg| \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B_{r}}K(x-y, t) dy\bigg| \leq \epsilon/2$$

as

$$ \int_{\mathbb R^n}K(x-y, t) dy = 1\ .$$

That is, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $T(\epsilon)$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$,

$$|u(x, t)| \leq \epsilon$$

whenever $t\geq T$. Wish you good luck with your qualifying exam!